# How to remove http://www. from php array

Tags: php

How to remove http:// www. from php array,

here is my code that displays a store url and I just want domain.com to be displayed instead of http://www.domain.com, also may show as http://domain.com

code: `<p class="store-url"><a href="<?php echo $url_out; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $stores_url; ?>`

It displays like this because of this function

```
<div class="store"> 

<?php // grab the store meta data 
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
$stores_url = esc_url(get_metadata(APP_TAX_STORE, $term->term_id, 'clpr_store_url', true));
$dest_url = esc_url(get_metadata(APP_TAX_STORE, $term->term_id, 'clpr_store_aff_url', true));

// if there's a store aff link, then cloak it. else use store url
if ($dest_url)
$url_out = esc_url(home_url(CLPR_STORE_REDIRECT_BASE_URL . $term->slug));
else
$url_out = $stores_url; 

?>
```

Comment: So to sum up, you want to remove a substring from a string, `$url_out`?

Comment: To those who are down-voting, please explain to OP why you're doing it so he can improve his question, if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php $stores_url = preg_replace('/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?/i', '', $stores_url); ?>
<p class="store-url"><a href="<?php echo $url_out; ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php echo $stores_url ?>
</p>
```

It will remove `http://` or `https://` from the beginning of the URL as well as `www` if it follows.

Comment: You're welcome, if it was a proper solution, you can go ahead and accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: feel free to answer my other questions